# How do i import JSON file consists more than 200 documents into mongodb

Tags: json, file, mongoimport

I have created a `demodb.json` file (having 10 documents) and kept it in my system's `D:\` drive

contents of `demodb.json` are:

```
[{"ID": 1,"Name": "Kabul","CountryCode": "AFG","District": "Kabol","Population": 1780000}, {"ID": 2,"Name": "Qandahar","CountryCode": "AFG","District": "Qandahar","Population": 237500}, {"ID": 3,"Name": "Herat","CountryCode": "AFG","District": "Herat","Population": 186800}, {"ID": 4,"Name": "Mazar-e-Sharif","CountryCode": "AFG","District": "Balkh","Population": 127800}, {"ID": 5,"Name": "Amsterdam","CountryCode": "NLD","District": "Noord-Holland","Population": 731200}, {"ID": 6,"Name": "Rotterdam","CountryCode": "NLD","District": "Zuid-Holland","Population": 593321}, {"ID": 7,"Name": "Haag","CountryCode": "NLD","District": "Zuid-Holland","Population": 440900}, {"ID": 8,"Name": "Utrecht","CountryCode": "NLD","District": "Utrecht","Population": 234323}, {"ID": 9,"Name": "Eindhoven","CountryCode": "NLD","District": "Noord-Brabant","Population": 201843}, {"ID": 10,"Name": "Tilburg","CountryCode": "NLD","District": "Noord-Brabant","Population": 193238}]
```

My Mongodb location is: `D:\SanMongoDB`

All my database and collections stored in `D:\SanMongoDB\MongoData`

contents of demodb-->city collection is as below

```
{  "_id":ObjectId("51892b40842d69f5fa21962f"),
   "Name": "India",
   "CountryCode": "IND",
   "District": "ODISHA",
   "Population": 2050000
}
```

I started Mongod server then open mongo client
In mongo client I did the following:

> use demodb
>   mongoimport -d demodb -c city --type json --file demodb.json --jsonarray

But i found error as below

`Thu May 09 08:21:57.861 Javascript execution failed:SyntaxError:Unexpected identifier`

Kindly suggest what I need to do so I can easily import the Json file into the exisiting database of Mongodb.

Comment: That is because the correct id is `_id`, not `ID`. So, `Unexpected identifier`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your stuff is in file.json, try `sed -e 's/ID/_id/g;s/\([^:]*\):\([^,}]*\)/"\1":"\2"/g' file.json | mongoimport --collection collection-name`. You can get [sed for Windows from GNUWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm). Let me know if you have further problems.

Here, `s/ID/_id/g` substitutes every occurrences of `ID` with `_id` in the file `file.json` and the second quotes every word to make your file [valid JSON](http://jsonlint.com). After the two transformations, mongoimport works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100 % sure but I think it should look like this :

Start mongod

use demodb

mongoimport -d [dbname] -c [collectionname] --demodb.json --jsonarray

some example

http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/mongodb-import-and-export-example/